# How to translate the "Choose File" button and the "No File chosen" labels in the "Attach File" page

Tags: attachment, translation, translation-workbench

I am trying to translate the standard "Attach File" page.

This is the page that is opened when you click on the "Attach File" button in every object attachment list:

[image]

I have succeeded on everything except the "Choose File" button and the "No File chosen" labels:

[image]

Is it possible?

If it is possible than - how?

Comment: That seems to be a button name which is dependent on the web browser settings

Comment: @kurunve so if I change my browser language it will change the labels?

Comment: @kurunve I have tested it, it works ok as you have noted. can you please write it as an answer  and I will accept it  - so others will also know?